# MongoDB - Getting rid of duplicate objects inside an array while keeping their original order

Tags: mongodb, duplicates, set

I have two collections with the following documents

**Collection #1**

```
{"_id": "1", "posts": [{"text": "all day long I dream about", "datetime": "123"}, {"text": "all day long ", "datetime": "321"}]}
```

**Collection #2**

```
{"_id": "1", "posts": [{"text": "all day long I dream about", "datetime": "123"}, {"text": "all day long ", "datetime": "8888"}, {"text": "I became very hungry after watching this movie...", "datetime": "8885"}]}
```

I'm merging collection #1 into collection #2

```
db.collection_1.aggregate([
            {
                '$merge': {'into': 'collection_2',  
                           'on': '_id',
                           'whenMatched': [
                               {'$addFields': {
                                   'posts': {
                                       '$concatArrays': [f'$posts',
                                                         f'$$new.posts']}}}],
                           'whenNotMatched': 'insert'
                           }
            }
        ])
```

By this merge the **posts** field contains all the 5 posts, including duplicates (the post with "text": "all day long I dream about").

At this point I wish to remove duplicates for **posts**. I'm doing this by using the following function

```
db.collection_2.aggregate([{"$project": {
            "posts": {"$setUnion": ["$posts", "$posts"]}}},
            {'$out': collection_2}])
```

This function works perfectly, all duplicate posts are gone. My problem is that because I'm using $setUnion I'm loosing the original order of the posts.

I wish to do everything directly on MongoDB server.

Any suggestions on how I can remove duplicate posts while preserving the original order of them?

Comment: Iterate through the array with duplicates manually, e.g. with $reduce. It will be slower but you will have full control.

Comment: @AlexBlex can you show an example of what you mean maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Merging arrays manually and remove duplicates:

- [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce) concatenated array (with duplicates)
- the reducer:

  - check [$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond) if the element $$this is already [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in) the carried  result $$value
  - if so - return $$value unchanged
  - otherwise add it to the array with $concatArrays

The code (the changed part is in $addFields ):

```
db.collection_1.aggregate([
        {
            '$merge': {'into': 'collection_2',  
                       'on': '_id',
                       'whenMatched': [

  {
    "$addFields": {
      "posts": {
        $reduce: {
          input: {
            "$concatArrays": [
              "$posts",
              "$$new.posts"
            ]
          },
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            "$cond": {
              "if": {
                "$in": [
                  "$$this",
                  "$$value"
                ]
              },
              "then": "$$value",
              "else": {
                "$concatArrays": [
                  "$$value",
                  [
                    "$$this"
                  ]
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }


                       'whenNotMatched': 'insert'
                       }
        }
    ])
```